# How to download and open a file with NS 6.0

Tags: nativescript, androidx

I'have migrate to *NativeScript 6.0* and need some help on how to download and open a file with Android support lib (AndroidX) in the *Downloads* folder.

Actually, in NS 5.x, i have used *FileProvider* from Android support lib (android.support.v4.content.FileProvider) and works great. After the migration, using (androidx.core.content.FileProvider), i have errors opening the App.

But in Android docs, i can't find any method or information to migrate the code for Native download and Open (Downloads Folder).

---

Previous Method:

```js
  private openFile(fileName: string, mimeType: string, extension: string) {
    try {
      if (isAndroid) {
        const intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        const context = applicationModule.android.context;
        console.log("android.ctx=", context);

        const nativeFile = new java.io.File(fileName);
        console.log("nativeFile=", nativeFile);

        const uri = android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.otisw.gescon.app.provider", nativeFile);

        intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
        intent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        const choosedIntent = android.content.Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file...");
        console.log("choosedIntent=>", choosedIntent);
        context.startActivity(choosedIntent);
      } else {
        // const documents = fs.knownFolders.currentApp();
        // const file = this.documents.getFile(fileName);
        const open = utils.ios.openFile(fileName);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Tried:

```js
  private openFile(fileName: string, mimeType: string, extension: string) {
    try {
      if (isAndroid) {
                const intent = androidx.core.content.IntentCompat.makeMainSelectorActivity(
                    "android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW",
                    "??"
                );
```

File reference.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts" />

/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android/androidx-26.d.ts" />
```

Does anyone tries to upgrade the code for Download and Open from NativeScript to new AndroidX or knows a workaround to do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [androidx.core.content.FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) on AndoridX and [android.support.v4.content.FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) in lower versions.

> With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version
>   of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The
>   AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also
>   includes the latest Jetpack components.
>
> You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts
>   (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*)
>   will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library
>   development will occur in the AndroidX library.
>
> We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You
>   should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.